# Issues with Android imports in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I just updated all the Android plugins for Eclipse and now it is no longer suggesting the appropriate Android class imports.

Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you also ran Help > Check for Updates. Then close down and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I also might add that after upgrading to Juno Service release 2, the SDK lost track of my Android plugins.  You may have to reinstall them

HELP-->Install New Software-->"Work with:" drop-down = Android plugins

Check both the developer tools and the NDK and go for it.

You may have to run eclipse as administrator to have privileges to do this update.

The symptom is the same as above, the SDK can not find such classes as android..xxx

Can someone suggest a way to re-hook the SDK to an existing set of plugins?  I could not find that.